# Chrome: This site can't be reached

Tags: google-chrome

Intermittently, I'm getting errors in Chrome like this:

[image]

Right now, I'm even getting it for the imgur site where the screenshot is saved.

**Edit:** It just happened again on StackOverflow.com. I was answering a question, and posted a screenshot. I then edited my answer, removed the screenshot and posted another screenshot. I could see the first screenshot just fine, but for the new screenshot I get the broken link and now I cannot get to the imgur site at all. **edit end**

When I open a different Chrome profile, I can get to these sites without a problem, so it's **NOT** an issue with the computer or network. My computer can see the sites just fine in a different session or in another browser. The problem is somewhere in the current Chrome profile and I need to fix it.

What does **NOT** work

- all the steps typically listed for network fixes, DNS reset, TCP/IP reset, LAN settings, VPN settings, proxy settings etc. Again, the computer can see the site, just the one Chrome session can't.
- clearing all cookies for the site
- clearing the cache
- disable all Chrome extensions and restart Chrome

What works (but I can't do that every time the problem comes up)

- restarting the computer
- creating a new Chrome profile, syncing all settings from the cloud

I get the problem between three times a day and three times a week. It's not life threatening but very annoying.
I run (and would like to keep running) these extensions:

- Ublock
- 1Password
- OneTab
- Send to OneNote

Does anyone have any idea what the cause could be and how to fix it? I've asked similar questions before, but no answers.

Comment: I get the problem between three times a day and three times a week. - Does this mean that apart from those three particular time,you can access the websites the rest part of the day with that same chrome session

Comment: Yes. I was on the site in the morning, closed the tab. Went back to the same site in the afternoon and get the error. Or here in the Stack network. Some questions simply won't show the images from imgur, others do.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall Chrome. There could be something wrong with your Chrome profile that's causing problems. Uninstall Chrome and make sure to check the box to delete browsing data. Then reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Which antivirus are you using?Try uninstalling or disabling them from settings..

Comment: @user52599 if AV were the problem, I would not be able to see the page in other Chrome sessions or browsers. Please read the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last year, and it was my bit defender interfering somehow. I had to go into bit defender settings and turn off one of the real time monitoring settings. I no longer have a bit defender so I’m afraid I can’t tell you now exactly which one it was.

Comment: How would this account for sites being available in one browser session, but not in the other?

Comment: I always seemed  to have trouble with just Google Chrome no matter the session....but didn’t seem to have problems if I used Firefox etc.. I had to dig around but eventually found help and the solution under the Google Chrome help and support, there are people there that help and answer questions whenever you can’t find the generic canned answer

Comment: And I am not saying that your problem is exactly the same as what my problem was, only  that the symptoms are very similar. In fact, I was trying to help a guy who’s having the same problem a couple of weeks ago on Reddit. I don’t know if he ever found the answer to his problems because he never responded back.